# Why am I having 2 router in my home (1 is from ISP)?

Tags: networking, internet

I use this ISP for some time and I love it because it have stable speed and great uptime.

One that I do not understand is the ISP installs 1 wireless router in my house, and it connects directly to the fiber optic cable outside and also, that modem connects to my other router (which I should bought it myself) via a UTP Cable (LAN). That second router I bought has internet access, and wireless network is working, it connects to my PC too. The first router from the ISP, does not have any internet connection (I tried to connect it directly to my notebook via UTP Cable and wireless).

[image: Here is the graph to help.]

So, what mechanism/technique that the ISP use? It seems bizarre that my router connects to a router that cannot connect to the internet?

Thank you!

Comment: You call device A a router, but how do you know it _is_ a router and not some other kind of device? What does it look like? What ports or appendages does it have?

Comment: Also: When you installed router B, did you have to configure VLANs or PPPoE in it?

Comment: The first router does have "internet connection", you are probably not setting up things correctly. Without knowing details, it's impossible to say what you need to do to make it work.

Comment: @user1686 It is a ZTE device which has some UTP ports, a fiber optic port (I do not know the cable name), wifi antennas. Ans yes i need to set pppoe on the second router I bought myself. But I don't think i configured VLAN or something.

Comment: Then the PPPoE thing is your answer to "no internet" right there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most common networks will contain a few things:

- Modem (aka Customer Premise Equipment or CPE)

  - This device acts as a translator between the technologies that your ISP provides, usual DOCSIS for Cable and GPON for Fiber (like yours), and commonly Ethernet (or UTP).
- Gateway (aka "Router")

  - This device acts as a barrier, implementing several common functions into one device. Network Address Translation (for multiple devices to use the same public IP address), firewall, Wi-Fi, and sometimes a network switch.

Theoretically, you could connect a device to the Modem, and it will retrieve an IP address like your modem would, and one can operate without a Gateway, but then you start losing out on useful features like Wi-Fi.